# kendo timepicker " yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.000Z" how to change hh:mm format

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-timepicker

I am using kendo ui using time picker 24h display success but I am get it data yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss 000z but I need hh:mm only. How to change it?

```
Get it time value :
"2018-10-07T19:30:00.000Z"

my need:
selected time only 09:10
```

[image]

Comment: Format property in should be "HH:mm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted the timepicker to display it in HH:mm, then format is the way to go
like :

```
$("#timepicker").kendoTimePicker({
    format: "HH:mm"
})
```

but if you wanted the value to be HH:mm you need to use `parseDate()` and `toString()`
like:

```
console.log("formatted value " + kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(this.value()), "HH:mm"));
```

Working example, check console log

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/js/kendo.all.min.js">
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/js/kendo.console.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<input id="timepicker" />
<script>
$("#timepicker").kendoTimePicker({
    format: "HH:mm",
   change: function(){
   console.log("raw value " + this.value());
      console.log("formatted value " + kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(this.value()), "HH:mm"));
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```